# iPhone SDK Bluetooth application test

Tags: iphone, sdk

I developed one Bluetooth application. I mean, I got it from Internet. Could I test this application in my simulator?

When I execute this application in simulator, it is showing only one message box:

> LOOKING FOR OTHER iPHONE OR iPOD TOUCH

My computer is mini Mac. There is Bluetooth. If we test it in my iPhone, does it work fine? Please help me.

Comment: Please add more clarity to this. I'm unsure what the question is. I do know that bluetooth is fairly limited in the SDK except in GameKit

Comment: i edited it... pls help me...
if u have any blue tooth application pls give me its link...

thank you..

Answer (score 1):

The simulator does not have bluetooth support.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth networking is not supported on the original iPhone or the first-generation iPod touch. It is also not supported in Simulator.
 please refer it
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html